# How to receive UDP packets from a specific remote client per UdpClient? (.Net 4.6)

Tags: c#, .net, udpclient

I'm trying to figure out how a server will distinguish between multiple clients that connect to it via TCP listener, and begin sending UDP messages to a UdpClient.

The TcpListner makes it easy for TCP, because a TcpClient is returned that I can attach to a specific client instance on the server. But how will I handle the UdpClient now since UDP is a connectionless protocol? I am also curious how the TcpClient knows which machine to send data back to in the first place, especially if its sitting behind a router.

I can't trust something like a unique id in udp packet headers, because those can always be forged or stolen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation for [UdpClient.Receive Method (IPEndPoint):](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> *remoteEP*
>   Type: System.Net.IPEndPoint
>   An IPEndPoint that represents the remote host from which the data was sent.

In other words, just use the `IPEndPoint` value that the `Receive()` method passes back to you. This will be a unique IP address and port for each client, which you can use as a key to match the datagram with your client state.

> I am also curious how the TcpClient knows which machine to send data back to in the first place, especially if its sitting behind a router

A connected socket maintains information about the remote endpoint. If the client is behind a NAT router, the remote endpoint IP address and port are of the router, and the router has a table that maps externally-visible addresses and ports to the clients which sit behind that router. See [Network Address Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation).